# current date to numeric code algorithm reversal

Tags: math

There is a software installer I need to use regularly in our office for our Document Management System that requires a code for the installer to proceed.
The code seems to be date specific.

I was wondering if anybody good with math might have an idea on how to work out the method used to generate the code so I don't have to call their helpdesk and wait 2-3hrs just for the 6-digit string.

Today's code (15/02/2013) is 836959.
Another day's code (06/02/2013) was 450001.

Is there any relation here or can it be reverse engineered?

Comment: do you have to pay to get the code?

Comment: no, it's just that they recently built this in because they don't want the software being installed on incompatible PC's or your basic PC "guru" redistributing it.  I'm forever rolling out new workstations and rebuilding virus infected workstations, so each time I go to install this software (whose licensing is counted by concurrent logged in users, not per install) I have to put my job on hold for a few hours while I wait for them to call me back.

Comment: there is every chance that the daily code is a randomly generated 5-digit numeric string... but I doubt it.  The installer is a local installer and has nothing to do with a server of theirs that it would need to communicate with to verify the 'random' code.  There'd have to be some mathematical relationship between the current date and the daily code that the installer/uninstaller uses...   I'm just not that good at math.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly a math question, it is a cryptography question, the function is probably a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)... from a math point of view, if the number of digits for the key is fixed then this is probably a [Surjective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function), meaning a function that maps dates to keys with possibly more than one date mapping to the same key.  With two datapoints it is difficult to even guess at what that function might be unless it is trivial... the more points you have, the more confidence you would have that you have found "the" function that they use, but you would never be sure.  The only way to be sure, is to disassemble the binary, which the license agreement probably precludes you from doing.